# Firebase Test lab no permission to create a test matrix

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I log in firebase with owner account and im trying to run robo test with test lab. How to fix this?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

Please go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/

On your Dashboard Top left Click +Enable APIs and Service.

Search and enable the  "Google Cloud Testing API".

Comment: I have also enabled the "Cloud Tool Results API". Please try without this API first and reply or edit this answer. Thank you!